# Mysql. How to select records with mutiple parameters (logical AND)

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value, multiplicity

I have 2 tables. One table keeps data name parameters, the second table has relation many-to-many. I want to select records which have entrance in multiplicity (logical AND). All I have written is filtering by logical OR. I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ap.id, ap.name, apr.ad
FROM 
    additioanal_parameters ap
JOIN additional_parameters_relation apr ON ap.id = apr.par_rel AND 
     apr.par_rel IN (109,114,111)
```

The output result is:

```
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "65"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "67"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "77"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "76"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "68"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "81"}
{id: "114", name: "VSC", ad_rel: "65"}
{id: "114", name: "VSC", ad_rel: "67"}
{id: "114", name: "VSC", ad_rel: "76"}
{id: "111", name: "ABS", ad_rel: "67"}
{id: "111", name: "ABS", ad_rel: "65"}
```

All I want now is return records like this

```
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "65"}
{id: "109", name: "ASC", ad_rel: "67"}
```

ad_rel = 65 has parameters in multiplicity (109, 114, 111) what is I expected to return.
ad_rel = 77 has parameters in (109), so this record is not interesting and etc.

I will be very appreciated for any help. Thanks

Comment: From the question, I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thx everyone. I have found a solution from @CBroe